# Пагинация Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Как достать переменную или массив где храниться общее количество страниц пагинации определенной категории ? сайт на OpenCart, при переходе на страницу пагинации которой не существует - выдает страницу и пишет просто что товар не найден, мне же нужно делать редирект на последнюю страницу пагинации, но проблема в том что я не могу получить последнюю страницу пагинации так как она не размечается, вот собственно вопрос - существует ли переменная в которой хранятся все страницы пагинации (категория - проверка по урл)

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, у вас в контролере есть следующие

```
$pagination = new Pagination();
$pagination->total = $product_total;
$pagination->page = $page;
$pagination->limit = $limit;
```

`$product_total` это общее число товаров `$limit` это число товаров на странице.
$page это номер текущей страницы 
последняя страница = `$product_total/$limit`
можете сделать проверку и редиректить пользователя на последнюю страницу если вам так необходимо.